# Can I use "I'm taking off" for "I'm leaving now"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrasal-verbs

I know people say "I'm gonna take off" often. But, can I also say "I'm taking off" as "I'm leaving now"?

Last time I used "I'm taking off", my American friend told me this sounded not natural.

I was told that I cannot use "i'm taking off" as "leaving" unless I mean "the airplane is taking off." (The question was not clear.)

Comment: gonna is popular speech for going to. take off is in dictionaries. Please show some research when you pose questions. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you understand my question.

Comment: *take off, split, bounce, get going,...* There are any number of colloquial alternatives to ***go / leave***, but it's probably best to stick with those two unless you know you're talking to people who definitely use one of those "idiomatic" variants themselves, since they won't be appropriate for ***all*** contexts.

Comment: @Lambie, and for your information, yes i did. Some people say "in AE, they don't say taking off for leaving, unless you mean your plane is taking off".

Comment: I consider your question a valid one, but more context will help clarify it. Can you tell us where you heard/saw that?

Comment: @Lambie, nobody says that. Alright, I guess it was not clear enough. But thanks for trying.

Comment: Some people certainly *do* say *I'm taking off* for *I'm leaving*, and I doubt the percentage who do so would be much different in the US, the UK, or Australia, for example. But just accept it as "valid" if you hear it, and *maybe* repeat it yourself *with those people*. Just don't commit to it as ***your*** standard verb for the context.

Comment: @Lambie They say, "taking off" is not used when you, say, leaving a party. They say you can only use "I'm taking off" when you are on an airplane, as the airplane is about to take off. My American friend said that, and that's why i asked this question.

Comment: Even just the comments here are enough to convince me this is Off Topic POB (just reflecting different opinions).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Does that include your own comments? take off also means to succeed.

Comment: @Lambie: To take off also means to ***parody*** (and probably other idiomatic senses that don't come to mind). But that doesn't directly relate to whether or not the OP should adopt the usage himself, for the "leave" (usually, ***hastily***) sense.

Comment: *...take off* can also mean to ***steal, kill, start a fight, start ranting***. And reflexively, if I say *I'm gonna take **myself** off*, that would usually carry the very specific implication *...to somewhere **private***.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica  As a noun: a take off (comedy), not really a verb. do a take off someone. But maybe you should try waving that in someone's else face. [joke]

Comment: @Lambie: I never mentioned the noun usage. A take off is also a noun referencing the *action* of a plane taking to the air, and probably other senses can apply to other senses of the collocation. But I never heard of the "start a fight" sense being used as a noun. Interestingly, the near-equivalent ***to kick off*** doesn't seem to allow the noun usage for the "become agitated / start fighting" sense - I've only ever encountered that one in the *very* specific sense of "the first kick / start of a **football match**".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your friend was incorrect, in general.  In my experience "I'm taking off" is a perfectly natural and common way for people to say that they are leaving.  As this is a colloquialism, however, it is quite possible that it is more or less common in different places or amongst different groups of people, so it is possible that amongst the group of people your friend knows it is not as common, and thus sounds more unusual to them.

In my experience, "I'm gonna take off" and "I'm taking off" both have roughly the same meaning.  They are often also said with "now" on the end, but whether or not they have "now" they all have an implication that you are actually leaving (i.e. just about to go out the door) right now.